# WiFi NDIS driver does not appear in the WHQL ndistest device list

Tags: windows, ndis

I maintain an NDIS 6.0 native WiFi driver. One of my missions is passing a WHQL test. To that end I installed version 1.6 of the Windows Logo Kit. I also installed my driver on a a Windows 7, 32-bit test machine. The device appears in the device manager and works correctly.

As a first step I tried to pass the stand-alone NDIS test. However when I run ndistest.exe, the device does not appear in the list of devices. The following screenshot demonstrates the problem:

[image: NDISTest screenshot]

My device should have appeared in the 'Support Devices' list, or in the 'Test Device' drop box, but it fails to appear in either.

Can someone point out what may cause a device to not appear in these lists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently we forgot to implement a couple of obligatory OIDs. If you encounter this problem, make sure that you implement all required OIDs.